# android: scheduling job every hour forever

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, firebase-job-dispatcher

I have a web service on my server that needs to be pinged every hour. For this, I am using an Android app to ping it every hour. I have tried using Alarm manager but it stops working after few hours and if I swipe exit it. I have tried using service but for some reason, that doesn't seem to work and my app keeps crashing. I have am thinking about using Firebase Job dispatcher. My requirement is that the app needs to ping the web service on my server every hour. This should go on for at least next 3-4 months.  Is there a way to accomplish this ? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have tried broadcast receiver with Alarm Manager but have not been able to sustain the firing for more then 4 hours.

Comment: Try GcmNetworkManager.this is what you need

Answer (score 2):

Jhon you can use firebase jobdispatcher. because it will support from api level 9. you can see below how to create job dispatcher and how to call it.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scheduleJob(this);
}

public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
    //creating new firebase job dispatcher
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    //creating new job and adding it with dispatcher
    Job job = createJob(dispatcher);
    dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
}

public static Job createJob(FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher){

    Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            //persist the task across boots
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            //.setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
            //call this service when the criteria are met.
            .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
            //unique id of the task
            .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")
            //don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            // We are mentioning that the job is periodic.
            .setRecurring(true)
            // Run between 30 - 60 seconds from now.
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(30, 60))
            // retry with exponential backoff
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            //.setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            //Run this job only when the network is available.
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK, Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING)
            .build();
    return job;
}

public static Job updateJob(FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher) {
    Job newJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            //update if any task with the given tag exists.
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            //Integrate the job you want to start.
            .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
            .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")
            // Run between 30 - 60 seconds from now.
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(30, 60))
            .build();
    return newJob;
}

public void cancelJob(Context context){

    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    //Cancel all the jobs for this package
    dispatcher.cancelAll();
    // Cancel the job for this tag
    dispatcher.cancel("UniqueTagForYourJob");

}}
```

**ScheduledJobService.java**

```
public class ScheduledJobService extends JobService {

private static final String TAG = ScheduledJobService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
    //Offloading work to a new thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            codeYouWantToRun(params);
        }
    }).start();

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}

public void codeYouWantToRun(final JobParameters parameters) {
    try {

        Log.d(TAG, "completeJob: " + "jobStarted");
        //This task takes 2 seconds to complete.
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Log.d(TAG, "completeJob: " + "jobFinished");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Tell the framework that the job has completed and doesnot needs to be reschedule
        jobFinished(parameters, true);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I second [Anantha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762925) but seems like job parameters are little off for your needs.

You can go over [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/become-a-pro-at-scheduling-tasks-in-android-1b955f75f430) to learn about the subtle differences between various Job schedulers.

As a matter of fact, even Google recommends using [Firebase Job Schedular](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) if the app needs to do a network communication due to various reasons. Please watch the attached video on the Github page for more info on the same. This also gives you basic code to kickstart your application. You can just change the job parameters to suit your needs

Hopefully, this below code should suit your requirement of triggering every one hour with a tolerance of 15 minutes

```
 FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(getContext()));
    final int periodicity = (int)TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1); // Every 1 hour periodicity expressed as seconds
    final int toleranceInterval = (int)TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(15); // a small(ish) window of time when triggering is OK

    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            // the JobService that will be called
            .setService(yourJobService.class)
            // uniquely identifies the job
            .setTag("my-unique-tag")
            // recurring job
            .setRecurring(true)
            // persist past a device reboot
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(periodicity, toleranceInterval))
            // overwrite an existing job with the same tag
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            // retry with exponential backoff
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
            .setConstraints(
                    // only run on an unmetered network
                    Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
            )
            .setExtras(schedulerextras)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Comment: setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER) needs <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> to persist after reboot

Answer (score 1):

Do you try broadcast receiver? I use Broadcast Receiver with Alarm Manager to vibrate every minute and it work fine. The only problem is that when device turn off or restarted, it not vibrate till I enter my application.

My test code.

```
 public void setAlarm() {
    alarmMgr =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmManagerActivity.this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("a.b.c.d");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 5 seconds
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()
            , (1000) * (60)
            , pi);
}
```

My receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
if ( intent.getAction().equals("a.b.c.d")) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Custom Broadcast01");
    Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(10000);
    }
    else
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "no this action for intent!");
}
```

> Broadcast receiver to start Alarm when device restart

```
<receiver
            android:name=".OnBootBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OnBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        setAlarm();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still new to Broadcast Receiver. If someone see my answer not useful or wrong please down vote my answer.

Comment: Hi Jaspreet Kaur, Can you reccomment me how to use android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED/ when I use it always error.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `JobScheduler`(api >21 ) and `GcmNetworkManager` (api<21) depending on the api level of android. [Check out this library from evernote which takes care of it.](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)